# FB Graph Api story-attachment-media get album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is possible to get album from [story-attachment-media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/story-attachment-media/) object?
Like a: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/OBJECT?fields=photos{webp_images}`
or: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/OBJECT?fields=album{photos{webp_images}}`
or: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/OBJECT?fields=albums.limit(1){photos{webp_images}}`

Comment: Do you have a publicly available example object? I can’t find one with a story attachment to test right now.

Comment: Meh, I really don't know how to do it for a public access...
But actually, I have posted on my facebook page link to outside page.
( In this case it was: http://www.zgloszenia-online.pl/sailingnet/regaty-20170609 )
Maybe that will be helpful :)

Greetings,
Mate

Comment: What does posting a link to an external object have to do with any albums?

Comment: Had wrongly asked, I like to get more photos sizes like albums does, not only full_picture

Comment: I don't think they provide that many sizes for external objects, just the thumbnail you find inside attachments, and full_picture.

Comment: And picture field :/
Hey post answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [from comments] I have posted on my facebook page link to outside page. [...] I like to get more photos sizes like albums does, not only full_picture

I don't think they provide that many sizes for external objects, normally just the thumbnail you find inside attachments, the full_picture, and picture.